# Is there a way to edit an image before saving it to the database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, qt, loopbackjs

Our images are being uploaded by the users on the web application (React) and being saved on the database by our API (Loopback).

The images will be used in our Qt application and they should have round corners. We have some processing limitations so we can't clip or mask the images on Qt.

We have some out of proportion images with dry corners breaking the layout right now and I need a way to crop them to the correct proportions with a border radius on all 4 corners. For our next application we should have two rounded corners and two squared ones but if this isn't possible I can try and change it.

What I have researched so far:

- Cropping libraries (lots of them, but most had rectangle or circle as options for shapes and no clear way to customize the shape).
- Ways to add a pre-saved mask to the alpha channel of the image (couldn't really figure out a way that would work).
- The HTML tag canvas (still trying this approach).

I'm willing to try almost anything as long as it doesn't involve major changes to the Qt application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the canvas approach, since you would have full customization which is useful since you mention you'll be changing the requirements later.

1. Create a canvas
2. Draw a rounded-rectangle mask (see these wonderful [answers 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18387192/6951428) [and 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19593950/6951428))

   - Use `ctx.clip()` after drawing a custom path.
   - Or use `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in'` after drawing a mask image
3. Draw the actual image with the desired width/height and stretch/fill behavior
4. Export the resulting image using `canvas.toDataURL()`

```js
let width = 300;
let height = 500;
let radius = 50;

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'); // document.createElement('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(radius, 0);
ctx.lineTo(width - radius, 0);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(width, 0, width, radius);
ctx.lineTo(width, height - radius);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(width, height, width - radius, height);
ctx.lineTo(radius, height);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0, height, 0, height - radius);
ctx.lineTo(0, radius);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0, 0, radius, 0);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.clip();

let imgUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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'
let image = new Image();
image.addEventListener('load', () => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
  console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
});
image.src = imgUrl;
```

```html
<canvas>
```

Comment: Yes! This is perfect! I was getting to a solution fairly similar to this one looking at some previous answers in here but yours compiled everything I needed! Thank you very much for your help